# Allow hop-by-hop header Django

Tags: python, django, wsgi, chunked

I'm writing a demo proxy server with Django 1.6 and Python 3.4. I get an error when the response has this header:

```
Transfer-Encoding=chunked
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 214, in __call__
    start_response(force_str(status), response_headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 236, in start_response
    assert not is_hop_by_hop(name),"Hop-by-hop headers not allowed"
AssertionError: Hop-by-hop headers not allowed
```

I find out this question: [Allow hop-by-hop headers in Django proxy middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889054/allow-hop-by-hop-headers-in-django-proxy-middleware) but seem like Django 1.6 don't have `basehttp._hop_headers`.

I run server with `python3.4 manage.py runserver`.

Please help

Comment: _"a demo proxy server with django"_? Why are you writing a proxy server in django? It would be better to use Python and something like [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/http/#header-utilities).

Comment: Similar issue here with Django 1.6 and Python 2.7.  I suspect it's how manage.py works.  Another member of my team was able to set the transfer-encoding header running under uWSGI, and it ran without error.

Comment: `_hop_headers` are now in [`wsgiref.util`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57113570/52499).

Answer (score 9):

The following HTTP/1.1 headers are hop-by-hop headers that wsgiref does not allowed:

```
  - Connection
  - Keep-Alive
  - Proxy-Authenticate
  - Proxy-Authorization
  - TE
  - Trailers
  - Transfer-Encoding
  - Upgrade
```

See:

1. [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html)
2. The code of wsgiref: [util.py](https://github.com/replit/empythoned/blob/master/dist/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/util.py#L163), [handlers.py](https://github.com/replit/empythoned/blob/master/dist/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py#L179)

---